# How convert native code to ASCII in Intellij IDEA (not in *.properties)?

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA has setting Transarent native-to-ascii conversion, that display native codes as readable symbols in *.properties files. How make similar behavior in file with other extensions (ex. *.ru).

Comment: -> *.ru.properties?

Comment: I dont have permission to change filename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need bundle *.ru with Properties types:
Settings->File Types->Properties - add "*.ru" (or ext that needed you)

Comment: In my situation(version 2020.2), just add file name pattern to Properties type didn't work for existing files. It only worked when I copy-paste and recreated the file.

Comment: @lidlesseye, 
1) try to drop caches of idea (File->Invalidate cashes)...
2) try to update idea (I think it is a bug and may be it is fixed).